# A representation of a finite group which is not completely reducible

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Maschke's theorem says that every *finite-dimensional* representation of a finite group is completely reducible.  Is there a simple example of an infinite-dimensional representation of a finite group which is not completely reducible?

EDIT: As mentioned in the answers, there is actually no finite-dimensional caveat in Maschke's theorem.  It seems that I just got unlucky, in the that the first couple of references I found included a finite-dimensional assumption.

Comment: I doubt it, it seems like we will be able to use the axiom of choice or Zorns lemma and get complements for each sub-representation, which would be enough

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was not able to find any reference for Maschke's theorem talking *only* about the finite dimensional representations.

The "modern" statement of Maschke's theorem (or at lest, the one ring theorists like) is this:

> For any commutative ring $R$ and finite group $G$, the group ring $R[G]$ is [semisimple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_ring#Semisimple_rings) iff $R$ is semisimple and the order of $G$ is a unit in $R$.

Semisimplicity, linked above, is the condition where all right $R$ modules split into sums of simple modules. This is the corresponding fact to the result in representation theory about all representations being completely reducible.

Now if $R$ is a field of characteristic zero, the order of $G$ is going to be a unit no matter what order it has, and furthermore, fields are semisimple. So in particular, you have a corollary:

> For any field $F$ of characteristic 0 and finite group $G$, the group ring $F[G]$ is semisimple, and hence all of its modules (=representations of $G$) are completely reducible.

When the order of $G$ divides the characteristic of a field $F$, $F[G]$ *does* have representations that are not completely reducible. The easiest example in that case would have to be $F[G]$ itself, which necessarily has a nonzero Jacobson radical.

As a toy example, you could take the cyclic group of order two $C_2=\{1,c\}$ and the field $F_2$ of order two, and consider its group algebra $F_2(C_2)$. You get a ring of four elements $\{0,1,c,1+c\}$. You can see that $(c+1)^2=0$, so that $\{0,c+1\}$ is the nilradical (which is the Jacobson radical in this case).

Answer (score 2):

For a ring $R$, not necessarily commutative, but with a multiplicative identity, a non-zero $R$-module is a direct sum of simple modules if and only if it is a sum of simple modules, if and only if every submodule has a complement. A representation of a finite group $G$ over $\mathbf{C}$ is the same thing as a $\mathbf{C}[G]$-module. Every $\mathbf{C}[G]$-module $M$, whether finite dimensional or not, has the property that every submodule has a complement (the proof of Maschke's theorem does not use that the module is finite dimensional, only that $G$ is finite). So by the quoted result, every $\mathbf{C}[G]$-module is a direct sum of simple submodules, that is, every complex representation of $G$ is completely reducible.

Comment: I just want to point out Serkan's observation (that $\langle gv : g \in G\rangle$ is finite dimensional) shows that every simple module is finite dimensional and that every representation is a sum of these finite-dimensional simple modules, and so a direct sum of (a subset of) these finite-dimensional simple modules.

Answer (score 0):

Take $Z_2\times Z_2$, with generators A and B. Consider the field K(t), where K is the field of two elements. Let $\phi(A)=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 1 \\      0 & 1 \      \end{array} } \right]$ and $\phi(B)=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & t\\      0 & 1 \      \end{array} } \right]$, where $t$ is a variable. Then you got a representation of the Klein-group in $GL(2,K(t))$ and it is not completely reducible.